# Xfce Escape keyboard shortcut shows Logout dialog

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro 20.0 with Xfce 4.14.

When I press Esccape key, it shows Logout dialog even if no such shortcut is configured :-(

I don't know how to unset this annoying shortcut.

Here is my keyboard shortcuts config:

```
> xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -lv                                                                                                                                                                              Mon 10 Aug 2020 01:15:38 PM UTC
/commands/custom/<Alt>F2/startup-notify    true
/commands/custom/<Alt>F3/startup-notify    true
/commands/custom/override                  true
/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>Delete      xflock4
/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>x           xkill
/commands/custom/<Primary>Escape           xfdesktop --menu
/commands/custom/<Primary><Shift>Print     xfce4-screenshooter -r
/commands/custom/Print                     xfce4-screenshooter -fd 1
/commands/custom/<Shift>Print              xfce4-screenshooter -wd 1
/commands/custom/<Super>f                  exo-open --launch FileManager
/commands/custom/<Super>t                  /usr/bin/terminator
/commands/custom/XF86WWW                   exo-open --launch WebBrowser
/commands/default/<Alt>F1                  xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu
/commands/default/<Alt>F2                  xfce4-appfinder --collapsed
/commands/default/<Alt>F2/startup-notify   true
/commands/default/<Alt>F3                  xfce4-appfinder
/commands/default/<Alt>F3/startup-notify   true
/commands/default/<Primary><Alt>Delete     xflock4
/commands/default/<Primary><Alt>l          xflock4
/commands/default/<Primary><Alt>t          exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator
/commands/default/<Primary>Escape          xfdesktop --menu
/commands/default/Print                    xfce4-screenshooter
/commands/default/<Super>p                 xfce4-display-settings --minimal
/commands/default/XF86Display              xfce4-display-settings --minimal
/commands/default/XF86Mail                 exo-open --launch MailReader
/commands/default/XF86WWW                  exo-open --launch WebBrowser
/providers                                 <<UNSUPPORTED>>
/xfwm4/custom/<Alt>F4                      close_window_key
/xfwm4/custom/<Alt><Shift>Tab              cycle_reverse_windows_key
/xfwm4/custom/<Alt>Tab                     cycle_windows_key
/xfwm4/custom/<Control><Shift><Alt>Left    move_window_left_key
/xfwm4/custom/<Control><Shift><Alt>Right   move_window_right_key
/xfwm4/custom/<Control><Shift><Alt>Up      move_window_up_key
/xfwm4/custom/override                     true
/xfwm4/custom/<Super>d                     show_desktop_key
/xfwm4/custom/<Super>Tab                   switch_window_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>Delete                 del_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>F10                    maximize_window_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>F11                    fullscreen_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>F12                    above_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>F4                     close_window_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>F6                     stick_window_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>F7                     move_window_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>F8                     resize_window_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>F9                     hide_window_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>Insert                 add_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt><Shift>Tab             cycle_reverse_windows_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>space                  popup_menu_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt>Tab                    cycle_windows_key
/xfwm4/default/Down                        down_key
/xfwm4/default/Escape                      cancel_key
/xfwm4/default/Left                        left_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>d             show_desktop_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>Down          down_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>End           move_window_next_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>Home          move_window_prev_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>KP_1          move_window_workspace_1_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>KP_2          move_window_workspace_2_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>KP_3          move_window_workspace_3_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>KP_4          move_window_workspace_4_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>KP_5          move_window_workspace_5_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>KP_6          move_window_workspace_6_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>KP_7          move_window_workspace_7_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>KP_8          move_window_workspace_8_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>KP_9          move_window_workspace_9_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>Left          left_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>Right         right_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>Up            up_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F1                 workspace_1_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F10                workspace_10_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F11                workspace_11_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F12                workspace_12_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F2                 workspace_2_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F3                 workspace_3_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F4                 workspace_4_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F5                 workspace_5_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F6                 workspace_6_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F7                 workspace_7_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F8                 workspace_8_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary>F9                 workspace_9_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Shift><Alt>Left   move_window_left_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Shift><Alt>Right  move_window_right_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Shift><Alt>Up     move_window_up_key
/xfwm4/default/Right                       right_key
/xfwm4/default/<Shift><Alt>Page_Down       lower_window_key
/xfwm4/default/<Shift><Alt>Page_Up         raise_window_key
/xfwm4/default/<Shift><Control><Alt>Down   move_window_down_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Shift><Control><Alt>Left   move_window_left_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Shift><Control><Alt>Right  move_window_right_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Shift><Control><Alt>Up     move_window_up_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Super>Tab                  switch_window_key
/xfwm4/default/Up                          up_key
```

I tried to unset following properties but it did not change anything...

- `/commands/custom/<Primary>Escape`
- `/commands/default/<Primary>Escape`
- `/xfwm4/default/Escape`

Any idea?

Comment: If you run out of ideas, log out, switch to a text terminal, run `mv ~/.config/xfce4 ~/.config/xfce4-bak`, log in again and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, my keyboard was broken :-(

Thanks for your help!